# SQL Combining fields in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-scripts

There is a script that displays two tables. Names of type String and counting of type Long.
How can I combine the same fields “Out of stock” in one field and separate fields “marriage”, “re-sorting” in one field “marriage / re-sorting” in one table. In doing so, save the types of two tables and get the combined values ​​in the new fields. And how not to display extra fields, for example, a form for employees, etc.
I know that you can use the CASE, WHEN, THEN structure. But I don’t understand how to correctly describe it in my script.

```
SELECT rl.reason AS reject_reason, COUNT(*)
FROM
    mp.reservation_log AS rl
    JOIN
    mp.store AS st ON rl.store_id = st.md_id
    JOIN mp.order_item oi ON oi.reserve_id=rl.reservation_id
    JOIN mp.sku s ON s.id=oi.item_id
    JOIN mp.product p ON p.id=s.product_id
WHERE rl.created_at > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND rl.is_successful=0
GROUP BY rl.reason;
```

Table example:

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UV0I.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help your question make sense.  Nothing in your query is called "marriage" or "out of stock" or whatever, so it is totally unclear what you are referring to.  Further, your first sentence says "two tables" but your query references *five*.

Comment: more tables yes, I attached the output that needs to be changed. Pay attention to this.

Comment: Even after your attached output (don't do that in a picture!), it is unclear what your answer is to the question `Nothing in your query is called "marriage" or "out of stock" or whatever, so it is totally unclear what you are referring to.`

Comment: I get these fields from a table reason, is that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* like you want to combine several reasons in the same group.

You can use a case expression as a no-aggregated column for this, like so:

```
select
    case 
        when r1.reason in ('marriage', 're-sorting') then 'marriage/re-sorting'
        else r1.reason
    end real_reason,
    count(*) cnt
from ...
where rl.created_at > current_date - interval 1 month and rl.is_successful = 0
group by real_reason
```

Side note: DATE(NOW()) is better written CURRENT_DATE .

Comment: Could you help me combine this with my request? I constantly get a lot of mistakes

Comment: @skydogs: you just have to replace the `...` in my answer with your `from` clause (including the `join`s).